# Using EXCEL to Count Cells dependent on other Cells in the Row - create a matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, sum, countif

I'm thinking this should be simple but can't figure it out -- given a table like this

[image: Original Table]

I want to create another table that sums up/counts when "x's" occur together for each name.  In other words, given Name1 is "x", how many times does that occur when Name2, Name3, or Name4 have an "x".  Think of it as when people are playing/working together on the same team.  Here's what I would like to get to.  Don't worry about formatting:

[image: after matrix]

Comment: Btw - that first row looks like it should be "na", 1, 0, 2...

Comment: yes that is right -- that's a typo on my part -- see I need this!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=IF(B$6=$A7,"NA",COUNTIFS(INDEX($B$2:$E$4,0,MATCH(B$6,$B$1:$E$1,0)),"x",INDEX($B$2:$E$4,0,MATCH($A7,$B$1:$E$1,0)),"x"))
```

[image]

---

If one has the dynamic array formula FILTER(), this also works:

```
=IF(B$6=$A7,"NA",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTER($A$2:$A$4,FILTER($B$2:$E$4,$B$1:$E$1=B$6)="x"),FILTER($A$2:$A$4,FILTER($B$2:$E$4,$B$1:$E$1=$A7)="x"),0))))
```

Comment: I'll have to dig into Filter but the first solution appears to work -- thanks for the solution.  Now what if instead of "x" it's "x", and "x1".  So two strings I'm matching on.  I think I can just put another "if" in the formula but is there anything that is more elegant?  Again, thanks for the answer --- I'm just not sharp enough.

Comment: @bulajim New questions get new posts